# Why is my website's CSS code not responsive in bootstrap studio?

Tags: html, css, responsive, mobile-website, bootstrap-studio

I have made my website in Bootstrap Studio with HTML and CSS

This is what my website looks like on PC:
[image: This is what my website looks like on PC]

I have tried to use @media to scale a box up when it is viewed on mobile:

```
.container_a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  color: #fafafa;
  background: #000000;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border: 2.4px solid #999;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  height: 33%;
  width: 30%;
}

.container_a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  container_a {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 10 px;
    color: #fafafa;
    background: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 2.4px solid #999;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    height: 33%;
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  container_a {
    width: 80%;
    height: 35%;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work:
[image: But it doesn't work]

Why does it not work?

Comment: You are missing the `.` before your class names in your media queries.

Comment: put your HTML code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer your question, since it's typo related and will be closed, but you can really reduce your CSS to something more manageable since you have a bunch of redundant code:

```css
.container_a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fafafa;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2.4px solid #999;
  /* Shorthand for border-radius */
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* combine into the translate shorthand */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Put your mobile styles here */
  width: 80%;
  height: 35%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container_a {
    /* Only add the properties that change */
    height: 33%;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```